# Move laravel to new server

Tags: laravel, dns, server, project, move

I have a laravel project and want to make a copy of it on another server and domain.

What I have done:

- Downloaded all the files on my computer
- Uploaded all the files to the
  new server
- Exported DB and imported to new DB
- Changed DB settings in
  .env

The new server public_html folder is the folder I'm using for laravel public_html. So file and folder structure should be the same as on the original server.

I thought this should be enough but all I get when I visit the new domain is this:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, [no address given] and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

What could possible be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did You run the below commands

```
sudo chmod 755 -R laravel-project-name            // ur project name
sudo chmod -R o+w laravel-project-name/storage    // same here
```

Can I ask which version and platform u using?
If u using ubuntu use the above neither google it yours.

Comment: I dont have SSH connection and cant access a terminal, is that necessary?

Comment: Laravel 5.1.5 on a linux server

Comment: yhea, you need to do that or use ftp to give permissions or connect your server admin

Comment: I have ftp-access, are there any tutorials on what I need to do?

Comment: do from ftp or contact the admin and just pass the commands with folder name